# How do I get the value returned from a function in Python & Vimscript?

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I'm using Python to write a vim plugin, but there's something wrong when dealing with Vimscript.

```
function! Login()  
python << EOF    
import vim, weibo
appkey = 'xxx'
appsecret = 'xxxxx'
callback_url = 'xxxxxxxx'
acs_token = 'xxxxx'
expr_in = 'xxxx'
client = weibo.APIClient(app_key=appkey, app_secret=appsecret,\
         redirect_uri=callback_url)
client.set_access_token(acs_token, expr_in)
del vim.current.buffer[:]  
EOF    
return client
endfunction


function! Post()  
python << EOF
import vim, weibo
try: 
    vim.command("let client = Login()")  # line1
    client.post.statuses__update(status="hello") # line2
except Exception, e:
    print e
EOF
endfunction
```

Here, there're always errors like "Undefined variable" and "Invalid expression" when I call `Post()`, but line2 always succeeds executing.

I've not learned Vimscript before, could anybody tell me what I should do to avoid those errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have now added your whole function...

The reason you get an undefined variable and Invalid expression in `Login()` is because the scope of client ends at `EOF`. At the return line vim does not know about `client` because it is only defined within the python block.

What you could do is just define a python function that does this for you inside `Post()`. Something like the following.

```
python << EOF
import vim, weibo
def Login():
    appkey = 'xxx'
    appsecret = 'xxxxx'
    callback_url = 'xxxxxxxx'
    acs_token = 'xxxxx'
    expr_in = 'xxxx'
    client = weibo.APIClient(app_key=appkey, app_secret=appsecret,\
             redirect_uri=callback_url)
    client.set_access_token(acs_token, expr_in)
    del vim.current.buffer[:]  
    return client
EOF

function! Post()  
python << EOF
try: 
    client = Login()
    client.post.statuses__update(status="hello")
except Exception, e:
    print e
EOF
endfunction
```

NOTE: Since everything is passed to the same instance of python you can just define `Login()` as a normal python function outside of the vim function and do what ever you want later. It does not need to be in the same python block.

---

Old Answer

You need to put the symbol `EOF` at the end of your python sections. Otherwise vim keeps feeding the commands to python.

```
python << EOF
```

The appropriate section from the vim help [`:h python-commands`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-commands) is copied below.

```
:[range]py[thon] << {endmarker}
{script}
{endmarker}
            Execute Python script {script}.

{endmarker} must NOT be preceded by any white space.  If {endmarker} is
omitted from after the "<<", a dot '.' must be used after {script}, like
for the |:append| and |:insert| commands.
This form of the |:python| command is mainly useful for including python code
in Vim scripts.
```

Your `{endmarker}` is `EOF`. However since you do not show the whole function I am not sure where you need to put `EOF`

---

As for your code.

```
vim.command("let obj = Login()")
```

This line is correct. If and only if Login() executes without error. However with the snippet you show Login has errors.

Comment: Sorry for my incompleted code, actually I did have an {endmarker} in my function, I just forgot to add it when writing the question..

Comment: @YakiangZhong Can you post the whole function? Cause thats the only thing wrong with your code right now.

Comment: There're two whole functions now :)

Comment: Yah no errors now! Thank you so much, I've learned a lot ! :)